# How to use if else condition properly to rectify the error

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
#!/bin/bash
$activity1 = zenity  --list  --text " select the option" --radiolist  --column "Select" --column "you are" FALSE "admin" TRUE "customer" ;


if [ $activity1  = "admin"]; then

 ( zenity --password --username );

else [ $activity1 = "customer" ]; then


( zenity --entry );\

--entry-text ""
fi
```

I got an error "Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "fi")" 
Can any one suggest me the answer?

Comment: You need a space before `]`. `bash` cares about such things, even though some languages (e.g. C or C++) don't...

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a condition after else.

You should either have

```
if [ $activity1  = "admin"]; then
   ( zenity --password --username );
else # no condition
   zenity --entry );\
   --entry-text ""
fi
```

or use elif

```
if [ $activity1  = "admin"]; then
   ( zenity --password --username );
elif [ $activity1 = "customer" ]; then
   ( zenity --entry );\
   --entry-text ""
fi
```